# How to process SWT Token from ACS-hosted login page

Tags: wcf, token, acs

I've set up a ACS domain with a Relaying Party to Authenticate a WCF Service.  On my client (website), I want to link to the Hosted Login Page that ACS provides for my Relaying Party.  I have the Return URL configured to respond to the same page, but whenever it returns the page currently throws this error:

```
 A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
 client (wresult="<t:RequestSecurityTo...")
```

How to do retrieve this SWT token and parse it to send off to the WCF service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET request validation feature is kicking in here (because of the angle brackets). Either turn off request validation for the page or when on .NET 4.5 you can set the request validation mode in web.config to 4.5.

Or use this: http://leastprivilege.com/2010/07/24/wif-asp-net-4-0-and-request-validation/

I would also recommend using SAML instead of SWT. Since this is what WCF understands by default.

Comment: thanks, do you recommend any resources for using SAML with WCF?  A msdn tutorial i followed used SWT.

Comment: As I said, it's the default. Look for wsfederationhttpbinding.